# How to add count for the same week using reduce JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a function using `reduce` that allows me to group an array of objects `{ date: '2019-03-11', count: 8 }` by weeks. So far, I was able to group dates by weeks but I am having trouble to add together `count` if the date falls in the same week.

```
const dates = [
  { date: '2019-03-11', count: 8 },
  { date: '2019-03-12', count: 7 },
  { date: '2019-03-09', count: 6 },
  { date: '2019-02-27', count: 10 },
  { date: '2019-02-26', count: 11 },
  { date: '2019-02-22', count: 12 },
  { date: '2019-04-21', count: 3 },
  { date: '2019-04-18', count: 2 },
  { date: '2019-04-17', count: 4 },
  { date: '2019-04-19', count: 5 }
];
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
  const onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  return Math.ceil(((this - onejan) / 86400000 + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7);
};

const groups = dates.reduce(function(acc, item) {
  const today = new Date(item.date);
  const weekNumber = today.getWeek(today);
  // check if the week number exists
  if (typeof acc[weekNumber] === 'undefined') {
    acc[weekNumber] = [];
  }

  acc[weekNumber].push(item.date, item.count);

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(groups);
```

**Current Result**

[image]

**Desired Result**

```
[
  { weekStart: '2019-02-17', count: 12 },
  { weekStart: '2019-02-24', count: 21 },
  { weekStart: '2019-03-03', count: 6 },
  { weekStart: '2019-03-10', count: 15 },
  { weekStart: '2019-04-14', count: 11 },
  { weekStart: '2019-04-21', count: 21 }
]
```

where `weekStart` is the first date of the week (Sunday) by which it was grouped

**SOLUTION**

```
const dates = [
  { date: '2019-02-24', count: 10 },
  { date: '2019-02-25', count: 11 },
  { date: '2019-02-26', count: 12 },
  { date: '2019-03-09', count: 8 },
  { date: '2019-03-10', count: 7 },
  { date: '2019-03-11', count: 6 },
  { date: '2019-04-14', count: 3 },
  { date: '2019-04-15', count: 2 },
  { date: '2019-04-16', count: 4 },
  { date: '2019-04-22', count: 5 }
];

/**
 * Returns the week number for this date.  dowOffset is the day of week the week
 * "starts" on for your locale - it can be from 0 to 6. If dowOffset is 1 (Monday),
 * the week returned is the ISO 8601 week number.
 * @param int dowOffset
 * @return int
 */
Date.prototype.getWeek = function(dowOffset) {
  /*getWeek() was developed by Nick Baicoianu at MeanFreePath: http://www.epoch-calendar.com */

  dowOffset = typeof dowOffset == 'int' ? dowOffset : 0; //default dowOffset to zero
  var newYear = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  var day = newYear.getDay() - dowOffset; //the day of week the year begins on
  day = day >= 0 ? day : day + 7;
  var daynum =
    Math.floor(
      (this.getTime() -
        newYear.getTime() -
        (this.getTimezoneOffset() - newYear.getTimezoneOffset()) * 60000) /
        86400000
    ) + 1;
  var weeknum;
  //if the year starts before the middle of a week
  if (day < 4) {
    weeknum = Math.floor((daynum + day - 1) / 7) + 1;
    if (weeknum > 52) {
      nYear = new Date(this.getFullYear() + 1, 0, 1);
      nday = nYear.getDay() - dowOffset;
      nday = nday >= 0 ? nday : nday + 7;
      /*if the next year starts before the middle of
           the week, it is week #1 of that year*/
      weeknum = nday < 4 ? 1 : 53;
    }
  } else {
    weeknum = Math.floor((daynum + day - 1) / 7);
  }
  return weeknum;
};

function getWeekStart(date) {
  var offset = new Date(date).getDay();
  return new Date(new Date(date) - offset * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    .toISOString()
    .slice(0, 10);
}

function groupWeeks(dates) {
  const groupsByWeekNumber = dates.reduce(function(acc, item) {
    const today = new Date(item.date);
    const weekNumber = today.getWeek();

    // check if the week number exists
    if (typeof acc[weekNumber] === 'undefined') {
      acc[weekNumber] = [];
    }

    acc[weekNumber].push(item);

    return acc;
  }, []);

  return groupsByWeekNumber.map(function(group) {
    return {
      weekStart: getWeekStart(group[0].date),
      count: group.reduce(function(acc, item) {
        return acc + item.count;
      }, 0)
    };
  });
}

console.log(groupWeeks(dates));
```

Comment: Do you have a function that creates first day of week from a week number?

Comment: @SalmanA here is the function that you are asking for `getWeekStart(date)`. I have already a solution, but it is solved in two steps. I do not think it is the best solution. If you could come up with a better solution I would appreciate it . There is also a solution provided by @Nina Scholz but to tell you the truth I do not really get it. Too complicated for my level, unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

You could take the weekday as offset and subtract the milliseconds from the given date.

Reducing works with a callback and a clsoure over the key with the week start date.

```
(m, { date, count }) =>                      // outer callback with map and object
    (k => m.set(k, (m.get(k) || 0) + count)) // closure over k and updating the count in map
    (getWeekStart(date))                     // get value for k
```

```js
function getWeekStart(date) {
    var offset = new Date(date).getDay();
    return new Date(new Date(date) - offset * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
}

const
    dates = [{ date: '2019-03-11', count: 8 }, { date: '2019-03-12', count: 7 }, { date: '2019-03-09', count: 6 }, { date: '2019-02-27', count: 10 }, { date: '2019-02-26', count: 11 }, { date: '2019-02-22', count: 12 }, { date: '2019-04-21', count: 3 }, { date: '2019-04-18', count: 2 }, { date: '2019-04-17', count: 4 }, { date: '2019-04-19', count: 5 }],
    result = Array.from(
        dates.reduce((m, { date, count }) =>
            (k => m.set(k, (m.get(k) || 0) + count))(getWeekStart(date)),
            new Map),
        ([date, count]) => ({ date, count })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: it works but I do not really understand how it is working ;(

Comment: I will accept the answer but to tell you the truth it is a first time when I see such a sintex. I do not really understand it.